# Is this correct get_template_part() in WordPress?

Tags: php, get-template-part

I just want to show the slider structure if it has posts...

is this correct?

```
<?php
if ( (have_posts() ) {
  get_template_part('slider');
}
?>
```

I think that works but I'm not sure if is the correct way to do that..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to enter `the_post();`, after `have_post()`,for more information on get_template_part(); refer to [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part)